# Xcode 4 - command line target with initial setup

Tags: ios, xcode4, xcodebuild, command-line-tool

I am implementing an app which has a dependency to a command line tool.
This is because there are some presets to do.
The command line tool is responsible to create a sqlite file with all initial information needed by the app (clearly speaking: its just a tool to add some initial data to the app).

Now the problem is, that during debugging everything works fine but if I'll do a release build, some errors occur.
The first error was

```
target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.tool', but there's no such
product type for the 'iphoneos' platform"
```

This was because my main app had the command line tool as a target dependency.
I solved this by removing the target dependency and added the build to a run script phase:

```
#Build the initial setup target
xcodebuild -target InitialCoreDataSetup -sdk macosx -configuration $CONFIGURATION

#Run initializing data target to get current sqlite file
cd "$CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR"
cd ..
cd "$CONFIGURATION"
current_dir=$(pwd)
./InitialCoreDataSetup "$current_dir" "$SRCROOT" "$CONFIGURATION"
```

Now the problem is, that I get the following error:

```
=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET InitialCoreDataSetup OF PROJECT XY WITH CONFIGURATION AdHoc     ===
Check dependencies
SDK Configuration Error: no wrapper for product type @
```

I have absolutely no idea how to fix this.
Any suggestions?

How do you provide your app with an initial sqlite file?

Thanks in advance for any help!
**EDIT**
At the moment the build phases of my app target are the following:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW: I finally got that working by the following line:

```
#Build the initial setup target
export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH="$SYMROOT/Debug"
/usr/bin/env -i xcodebuild -target InitialCoreDataSetup -sdk "macosx" -configuration Debug OBJROOT="$SYMROOT/Debug" SYMROOT="$SYMROOT"
echo "$SYMROOT/Debug"
#Run initializing data target to get current sqlite file
cd "$SYMROOT/Debug"
./InitialCoreDataSetup "$SYMROOT/Debug" "$SRCROOT" "$CONFIGURATION"
```

The trick is to start the initialCoreDataSetup always in DEBUG mode

Comment: Using the `/usr/bin/env -i` for calling xcodebuild solved this message: `SDK Configuration Error: no wrapper for product type @` for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest letting Xcode do the build in this situation since you should be able to generate the sqllite file by using a build rule to run a script before the other build rules run.

[image]

Comment: Okay, could you specify a little bit? I need a target dependency to the InitialCoreDataSetup target from my main app target and then add a build rule to my app target with the script shown above (to run the target built by xcode via target dependency) ?

Comment: I think the Build Phase (as you have it in your answer) is a better place than Build Rules as I suggested.  Are you still running into problems when you do it like this, and what are the problems?